# How to fix this error "runtime.main: undefined main.init"

Tags: go

Trying run a simple hello world go program returns an error.

```
# command-line-arguments
runtime.main: undefined: main.init
runtime.main: undefined: main.main
```

The file contents:

```
package main    
import "fmt"
func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

`main` is obviously defined and adding `func init() {}` doesn't help.

Both the `run` and `build` commands result in the same error.

```
go build hello_test.go
go run hello_test.go
```

Comment: You probably don't want to name your file ending in `_test` unless it's a unit test file.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Rename hello_test.go to e.g. hello.go and it should work as expected. Go source files ending in _test are special (for the go build system). They're reserved for the `go test` command.

Comment: So what if my app is just a util without any main, do I need to provide a dummy main to avoid this problem by go get?